# "There's no telling": An "-ing" verb after "there is no" as a way of expressing the idea of the impossibility of an action

Tags: gerunds

There is an expression "there's no telling" and a proverb "There's no accounting for taste", the meanings being clearly explained [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/there%27s+no+telling) and [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There%27s+no+accounting+for+taste).

My question is this:

Is there any particular grammar rule for this ***("there's no" +  an "-ing" verb)*** construction,  for hard as I tried, the only explanation I did find was in the entry "No" [in here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=3Mt6I-jiLecC&pg=PA478&dq=%22there%27s+no+doing%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW7KuF2u7QAhXEFywKHYZeB8oQ6AEIajAJ#v=onepage&q=%22there's%20no%20doing%22&f=false).

Would it be right to say that this construction may be used to express the idea of the impossibility of an action, for example:

> There's no making her change her mind.
>
> There's no persuading him into selling his old car.
>
> There's no beating him at tennis.
>
> There was no denying that she had a lovely figure?

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing your third example, "There's no winning him at tennis"--this is ungrammatical because *win* does not take the defeated party as object, but that error is not relevant to your question.

Comment: Your example #3 should be *There's no **beating** him at tennis* (idiomatically, *winning* doesn't work like that). Other than that, they're all perfectly grammatical, but in practice #1 would usually be *There's no changing her mind*, and #2 would be *There's no persuading him to sell his old car*. But apart from the well-established idiomatic usage *There's no denying [that] [uncontested assertion]*, they're all a bit "affected" in modern conversational contexts. And the whole construction is effectively informal, so it should be used with care.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you very much for highly informative notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on context, the construction

> There's no "-ing"

can either mean the *impossibility* or the *prohibition* of an action

> **There's no winning** in tennis against him.
>   *it's impossible to beat him in tennis*
>
> **There's no talking** in the library.
>   *one is not allowed to talk in the library*

Comment: To me, these two meanings have a very different feel: the prohibition seems literal (there might be a sign up saying "No talking!", whereas the impossibility is an idiom, and is much happier with certain verbs ("telling", "persuading", "talking to", "denying", "stopping", "holding", that I can think of) that with any others. Most of these are about making somebody do or not do something.